# Unable to authenticate iMessage on MBP, but working on iPhone/iPad

Tags: icloud, catalina, messages

Yesterday, I tried to send a text through iMessage on my MBP 13" (2020) only find it not sent about 10 minutes later. I tried sending it again, the same outcome.

I sent the message directly through my iPhone SE (2020) without any problems. Fact: text service is working fine.

I decided to logout/login to iCloud on my MBP. This of course necessitated me to reconnect my iPhone and iPad to my iCloud account. Those reconnect without any problem.

The problem came with the MBP. iMessage asks me to log in with my Apple ID and I get the following error message:

[image: Could not sign in to iMessage.]

> Could not sign in to iMessage.
> An error occurred during activation. Try again.

I have tried multiple times to connect/authenticate iMessage without success. I am wondering if a preference file has been corrupted and is unable to authenticate. How can I fix this error and reconnect iMessage to iCloud?

MBP 13" (2020): running 10.15.6